# Parse Text input and get Text output (not String) with Parsec3

Tags: string, haskell, text, parsec

I see that Parsec3 handles `Text` (not `String`) input, so I would like to convert an old `String` parser to get Text output. Other libraries I am using also uses `Text`, so that would reduce the number of conversions needed.

Now, the `parsec3` library seems to do what it says (handle both `Text` and `String` input), this example is from within gchi:

```
Text.Parsec.Text Text.Parsec Data.Text> parseTest (many1 $  char 's') (pack "sss")
"sss"
Text.Parsec.Text Text.Parsec Data.Text> parseTest (many1 $  char 's') "sss"
"sss"
```

So, both `Text` (first case) and `String` (second case) works.

Now, In my real, converted, parser (sorry I have to piece together some remote parts of the code here to make a complete example)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
data UmeQueryPart = MidQuery Text Text MatchType

data MatchType = Strict | Fuzzy deriving Show

funcMT :: Text -> MatchType
funcMT mt = case mt of
        "~" -> Fuzzy
        _ -> Strict

midOfQuery :: Parser UmeQueryPart
midOfQuery = do
    spaces
    string "MidOf"
    spaces
    char '('
    spaces
    clabeltype <- many1 alphaNum
    spaces
    sep <- try( char ',') <|> char '~'
    spaces
    plabeltype <- many1 alphaNum
    spaces
    char ')'
    spaces
    return $ MidQuery (pack plabeltype) (pack clabeltype) (funcMT sep)
```

I find myself with a lot of errors like this with regards to the funcMT call

```
UmeQueryParser.hs:456:96:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Text’
    Expected type: Text
      Actual type: String
    In the first argument of ‘funcMT’, namely ‘sep’
    In the fifth argument of ‘ midOfQuery’, namely ‘(funcMT sep)’
```

and if I don't explicitly `pack` the captures text in the code sample above, this:

```
UmeQueryParser.hs:288:26:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the first argument of ‘ midOfQuery’, namely ‘(plabeltype)’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘StartQuery (plabeltype) (clabeltype) (funcMT sep)’
```

So, it seems that I need to convert captured strings explicitly to `Text` in the output.

So, why do I need to go through a step converting from `String`or `Char` to `Text` when the point was to do `Text -> Text` parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make your own `Text` parser, something simple like

```
midOfQuery :: Parser UmeQueryPart
midOfQuery = do
    spaces
    lexeme $ string "MidOf"
    lexeme $ char '('
    clabeltype <- lexeme alphaNums
    sep <- lexeme $ try (char ',') <|> char '~'
    plabeltype <- lexeme alphaNums
    lexeme $ char ')'
    return $ MidQuery plabeltype clabeltype (funcMT sep)
  where
    alphaNums = pack <$> many1 alphaNum
    lexeme p = p <* spaces
```

or, slightly more compact (but I think still more readable):

```
midOfQuery :: Parser UmeQueryPart
midOfQuery = spaces *> lexeme (string "MidOf") *> parens (toQuery <$> lexeme alphaNums <*> lexeme matchType <*> lexeme alphaNums)
  where
    lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
    lexeme p = p <* spaces

    alphaNums = pack <$> many1 alphaNum

    parens = between (lexeme $ char '(') (lexeme $ char ')')

    matchType = Fuzzy <$ char '~' <|>
                Strict <$ char ','

    toQuery cLabelType sep pLabelType = MidQuery pLabelType cLabelType sep
```

Comment: `    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Stream s m Char
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    When checking that ‘lexeme’ has the inferred type
      lexeme :: forall a s u (m :: * -> *).
                Stream s m Char =>
                ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m a`

Comment: I can't reproduce it locally; however, you could either turn on `FlexibleContexts` or give it a type signature `lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work now. Thank you for helping me see that the parser may be quite a bit more compact than my example.